# Redshift LISTAGG frame clause

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to aggregate strings, but limited to only the preceding rows, not the whole partition. Does anyone know how to do this in Redshift?

What I am trying to achieve is the `appended_event_namespace` column below.

[image]

This is what I've tried so far.

```
LISTAGG(event_namespace, '/')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tstamp_true)
OVER (PARTITION BY acct_id) AS appended_event_namespace
```

This results in the full `ApplicationLaunch/CategoryBrowse/NotificationCenter/UserProfile` aggregation on every single row instead of what is in the desired screenshot.

The difficulty is in getting it to only append up to the current row since there doesn't seem to be a frame-clause for Redshift's LISTAGG(). Thanks for any ideas that may help.

Comment: Redshift does not support that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack this together with another query. Start with your appended_event_namespace as the result of your original `LISTAGG`

```
SELECT event_namespace,
  SUBSTRING(appended_event_namespace,
            1, 
            POSITION(event_namespace,appended_event_namespace) + LEN(event_namespace) - 1
  ) as appended_event_namespace_cum
FROM your_table;
```

Basically, you take your aggregated, ordered string, and then take the first N characters where N is ([where it appears in the aggregated string ]+[its length]), which will cut out everything after that item. This gives you a cumulative namespace.

Comment: Thanks @Pdubbs. My example was probably not clear enough, but if a user cycled between components they could build a chain of namespaces like this `CategoryBrowse/NotificationCenter/CategoryBrowse`. Then substring matching wouldn't know which one to truncate at.

Comment: Ahh, that's tougher. I don't have a redshift cluster up right now: what does `REGEX_SUBSTR(appended_event_namespace,'[^.]*'||event_namespace)` return (trying to select arbitrary string ending in the current item)?

Comment: With Redshift I've always ran into problems trying to do concats for the pattern field in `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`. It would always complain about needing a valid UTF-8 literal.

If I hard coded an example though with `[^.]*CategoryBrowse`, it would return the longest string ending with CategoryBrowse. It could be matching against a CategoryBrowse that occurred significantly later.

Answer (score 0):

`LISTAGG` with frame clause is not supported in RS yet. If you have some columns that you can use for partitioning and ordering you can make a self join (not so performant but would accomplish what you want):

```
SELECT 
 t1.id
,t2.tstamp_true
,t1.event_namespace
,LISTAGG(t2.event_namespace,'/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.tstamp_true)
FROM your_table t1
JOIN your_table t2
ON t1.id=t2.id
AND t1.tstamp_true>=t2.tstamp_true
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid self join you can build a JSON with the following structure using LISTAGG:

```
[{tstamp_true_1,event_namespace_1},{tstamp_true_N,event_namespace_N},...]
```

and write a Python UDF that takes such JSON for the given group of rows and `tstamp_true` of the given row and returns the path (the function would need to filter the `tstamp_true_N` values earlier than the second parameter and concatenate filtered `event_namespace_N` values for the output)